# Closeable Chip on Mudblazor fileupload

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

How can I create a closeable chip on Mudblazor Fileupload Drag&Drop?
Here is an example: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GYwHEQvURJEkHBcX

```
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar

<MudStack Style="width: 100%">
    <MudFileUpload T="IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile>" OnFilesChanged="OnInputFileChanged" Hidden="false" Class="flex-1" InputClass="absolute mud-width-full mud-height-full overflow-hidden z-20" InputStyle="opacity:0"
                   @ondragenter="@SetDragClass" @ondragleave="@ClearDragClass" @ondragend="@ClearDragClass">
        <ButtonTemplate>
            <MudPaper Height="300px" Outlined="true" Class="@DragClass">
                <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Drag and drop files here or click</MudText>
                @foreach (var file in fileNames)
                {
                    <MudChip Color="Color.Dark" Text="@file" OnClose="Closed" />
                }
            </MudPaper>
        </ButtonTemplate>
    </MudFileUpload>
    <MudToolBar DisableGutters="true" Class="gap-4">
        <MudButton OnClick="Upload" Disabled="@(!fileNames.Any())" Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Filled">Upload</MudButton>
        <MudButton OnClick="Clear" Disabled="@(!fileNames.Any())" Color="Color.Error" Variant="Variant.Filled">Clear</MudButton>
    </MudToolBar>
</MudStack>
@code {
    private static string DefaultDragClass = "relative rounded-lg border-2 border-dashed pa-4 mt-4 mud-width-full mud-height-full z-10";
    private string DragClass = DefaultDragClass;
    private List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();

    private void OnInputFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        ClearDragClass();
        var files = e.GetMultipleFiles();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            fileNames.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }

    void Closed(MudChip chip) {
        fileNames.Remove(chip.Text);
    }

    private async Task Clear()
    {
        fileNames.Clear();
        ClearDragClass();
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
    private void Upload()
    {
        //Upload the files here
        Snackbar.Configuration.PositionClass = Defaults.Classes.Position.TopCenter;
        Snackbar.Add("TODO: Upload your files!", Severity.Normal);
    }

    private void SetDragClass()
    {
        DragClass = $"{DefaultDragClass} mud-border-primary";
    }

    private void ClearDragClass()
    {
        DragClass = DefaultDragClass;
    }
}
```

The chip is not clickable and if I change the Z-Index of the MudFileUpload control it collapses. I also tried to add Z-Index above 20 to the chip but I still cannot click it.

Comment: Running your example I am able to upload a file, the file shows as a chip in the drag and drop zone. If I click on the chip, the file upload dialog comes back up. If I click the x, it does not remove the uploaded file. What is the behavior you're expecting when clicking on the chip?

Comment: I want to remove the uploaded file and the chip OnClose button to be clickable without the upload dialog showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X button is not clickable, you have to put The "MudChip" outside the MudFileUpload tag like this :

```html
<MudStack Style="width: 100%">
    <MudFileUpload T="IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile>" OnFilesChanged="OnInputFileChanged" Hidden="false" Class="flex-1" InputClass="absolute mud-width-full mud-height-full overflow-hidden z-20" InputStyle="opacity:0"
                   @ondragenter="@SetDragClass" @ondragleave="@ClearDragClass" @ondragend="@ClearDragClass">
        <ButtonTemplate>
            <MudPaper Height="300px" Outlined="true" Class="@DragClass">
                <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Drag and drop files here or click</MudText>
            </MudPaper>
        </ButtonTemplate>
    </MudFileUpload>
    @foreach (var file in fileNames)
    {
        <MudChip Color="Color.Dark" Text="@file" OnClose="Closed" />
    }
    <MudToolBar DisableGutters="true" Class="gap-4">
        <MudButton OnClick="Upload" Disabled="@(!fileNames.Any())" Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Filled">Upload</MudButton>
        <MudButton OnClick="Clear" Disabled="@(!fileNames.Any())" Color="Color.Error" Variant="Variant.Filled">Clear</MudButton>
    </MudToolBar>
</MudStack>
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes the button clickable but the MudChips are outside of the MudPaper. I want them inside, do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: All the elements inside "ButtonTemplate" are going to be unclickable, you can play with Class and Style or put the "MudPaper" tag outside of the "MudFileUpload" tag to make the MudChips clickable inside. but if you do so, you can't click anywhere to upload a file

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks, I just used negative margin to move the chips up where I wanted them.

Answer (score 0):

Using negative margin like stated above is not ideal for responsive UIs. Instead I solved this by dynamically updating the height of the internal input element based on if you are dragging over the mudpaper.

This way the input doesn't block the mudchips, but still functions as normal when dragging a file over the mudpaper, the click behavior won't work but you can still restore this with some JS that clicks the button for opening the file picker when you click on the mudpaper.

```html
<MudStack Style="width: 100%">
    <MudFileUpload  
        T="IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile>"
        AppendMultipleFiles
        OnFilesChanged="OnFilesChanged"
        Hidden="@false"
        InputClass="@InputClass"
        InputStyle="opacity:0"
        @ondragleave="@OnDragLeave"
        @ondragend="@OnDragLeave"
    >
         <ButtonTemplate>
            <MudPaper 
                Height="300px"
                Outlined="true"
                Class="@_dragClass"
                @ondragenter="OnDragEnter"
                @onclick="OpenFilePicker"
            >
                @if (!Files.Any())
                {
                    <MudStack AlignItems="AlignItems.Center" Justify="Justify.Center" Style="height: 100%">
                        <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.FileUpload" Size="Size.Large" Color="Color.Primary" />
                    </MudStack>
                }
                <div class="relative d-flex z-30">
                    @foreach (var file in Files)
                    {
                        <MudChip Icon="@file.Name.GetMudIconBasedOnFileName()"
                                 Text="@file.Name"
                                 Color="Color.Primary"
                                 OnClose="() => RemoveFile(file)"
                                 Class="relative z-30" />
                    }
                </div>
            </MudPaper>
            <MudToolBar DisableGutters="true"
                        Class="relative d-flex justify-space-between gap-4 z-30">
                <MudButton id="openFilePickerButton" 
                           HtmlTag="label"
                           Color="Color.Primary"
                           for="@context.Id"
                           Variant="Variant.Filled">
                    Open file picker
                </MudButton>
                <MudButton OnClick="Clear"
                           Color="Color.Error"
                           Disabled="!Files.Any()"
                           Variant="Variant.Filled">
                    Clear
                </MudButton>
            </MudToolBar>
        </ButtonTemplate>
    </MudFileUpload>
</MudStack>
```

```
public sealed partial class FileUploadContainer
{
    private const string DefaultDragClass = "relative rounded-lg border-2 border-dashed pa-4 mud-width-full mud-height-full z-10";
    private const string DisabledInputClass = "absolute mud-width-full overflow-hidden z-20";
    private const string EnabledInputClass = DisabledInputClass + " mud-height-full";

    [Parameter] public List<IBrowserFile> Files { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<List<IBrowserFile>> FilesChanged { get; set; }

    [Inject] private IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

    private IJSObjectReference _jsModule;
    private string _dragClass = DefaultDragClass;

    // disable dragdrop when not dragging to make the chips clickable in the input field
    private bool _dragDropEnabled = false;
    private string InputClass => _dragDropEnabled ? EnabledInputClass : DisabledInputClass;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _jsModule = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Shared/FileUploadContainer.razor.js");
    }

    private async Task Clear()
    {
        Files.Clear();
        await FilesChanged.InvokeAsync(Files);
    }

    private async Task RemoveFile(IBrowserFile file)
    {
        Files.Remove(file);
        await FilesChanged.InvokeAsync(Files);
    }

    private async Task OnFilesChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        OnDragLeave();

        var newFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles();
        
        Files.AddRange(newFiles);
        await FilesChanged.InvokeAsync(Files);
    }

    private void OnDragEnter()
    {
        _dragDropEnabled = true;
        _dragClass = $"{DefaultDragClass} mud-border-primary";
    }

    private void OnDragLeave()
    {
        _dragClass = DefaultDragClass;
        _dragDropEnabled = false;
    }
    
    private async Task OpenFilePicker()
    {
        await _jsModule.InvokeVoidAsync("openFilePicker");
    }
}
```

```js
export function openFilePicker() {
    var button = document.getElementById('openFilePickerButton');
    button.click();
}
```